# How to indicate the multi index columns using read_sql_query (pandas dataframes)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a table with the following columns:

```
| Date | ProductId | SubProductId | Value |
```

I am trying to retrieve the data from that table and to put it in a pandas DataFrame.

I want the DataFrame to have the following structure:

- index: dates
- columns: products
- sub-columns: sub-products

> ```
> (products)    1              2               ...          
> (subproducts) 1    2    3    1    2    3     ...     
> date
> 2015-01-02   val val val   ...
> 2015-01-03   val val val   ...
> 2015-01-04   ...  
> 2015-01-05     
> ...
> ```

I already have dataframes with the products and the subproducts and the dates.

I understand that I need to use the **MultiIndex**, here is what I tried:

```
query ="SELECT Date, ProductId, SubProductId, Value " \
    " FROM table "\
    " WHERE SubProductId in (1,2,3)"\
    " AND ProductId in (1,2,3)"\
    " AND Date BETWEEN '2015-01-02' AND '2015-01-08' "\
    " GROUP BY Date, ProductId, SubProductId, Value "\
    " ORDER BY Date, ProductId, SubProductId "  



df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, index_col=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_products['products'].tolist(), df_subproducts['subproducts'].tolist()])
```

But it does not work because the query returns a vector of "value" (shape is nb of value x 1), while I need to have a matrix (shape: nb of distinct dates x (nb of subproducts*nb of prodcuts)) in the dataframe.

How can it be achieved:

- directly via the read sql query ?
- or  by "trandofrming" the dataframe once the database values inserted in ?

NB: I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use [unstack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) method:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, index_col=['Date','ProductID','SubProductId']) \
       .unstack(['ProductID','SubProductId'])
```

Demo:

```
In [413]: df
Out[413]:
          Date  ProductID  SubProductId  Value
0   2015-01-02          1             1     11
1   2015-01-02          1             2     12
2   2015-01-02          1             3     13
3   2015-01-02          2             1     14
4   2015-01-02          2             2     15
5   2015-01-02          2             3     16
6   2015-01-03          1             1     17
7   2015-01-03          1             2     18
8   2015-01-03          1             3     19
9   2015-01-03          2             1     20
10  2015-01-03          2             2     21

In [414]: df.set_index(['Date','ProductID','SubProductId']).unstack(['ProductID','SubProductId'])
Out[414]:
             Value
ProductID        1                 2
SubProductId     1     2     3     1     2     3
Date
2015-01-02    11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  16.0
2015-01-03    17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0  21.0   NaN
```

Comment: Just noticed: when doing so if there are some NaN Values for given date, product, subproduct, it will place the subcolumn at the end of the dataframe and not in the Product column. How to fix it ?

Comment: @Arty, could you please open a new question with a reproducible sample data set?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table('Value', 'Date', ['ProductId', 'SubProductId'])
```

***demo***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Date=pd.date_range('2017-03-31', periods=2).repeat(9),
        ProductId=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3] * 2,
        SubProductId=list('abc') * 6,
        Value=np.random.randint(10, size=18)
    ))

print(df)

         Date  ProductId SubProductId  Value
0  2017-03-31          1            a      8
1  2017-03-31          1            b      2
2  2017-03-31          1            c      5
3  2017-03-31          2            a      4
4  2017-03-31          2            b      3
5  2017-03-31          2            c      2
6  2017-03-31          3            a      9
7  2017-03-31          3            b      3
8  2017-03-31          3            c      1
9  2017-04-01          1            a      3
10 2017-04-01          1            b      5
11 2017-04-01          1            c      7
12 2017-04-01          2            a      3
13 2017-04-01          2            b      6
14 2017-04-01          2            c      4
15 2017-04-01          3            a      5
16 2017-04-01          3            b      2
17 2017-04-01          3            c      0
```

---

```
df.pivot_table('Value', 'Date', ['ProductId', 'SubProductId'])

ProductId     1        2        3      
SubProductId  a  b  c  a  b  c  a  b  c
Date                                   
2017-03-31    8  2  5  4  3  2  9  3  1
2017-04-01    3  5  7  3  6  4  5  2  0
```